# VBA paste as values not formulas

Tags: vba

I need to modify below's code so that it copies values instead of formulas, but I don't know how to modify this. Can you help me out?

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim myDataRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim iCnt As Integer
Dim sMail_ids As String
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim FileExt As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileFullPath As String
Dim FileFormat As Variant
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    Wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:K32").Copy Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    Wb2.Sheets(1).Name = Wb1.ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: `Wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:K32").Copy ` 
`Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Searching for "[vba] paste as values" gives 4558 results! Even searching for "[vba] paste as values not formulas" gives 541 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the fastest way (using an array and not involve clipboard):

```
'your code...
'replace  Wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:K32").Copy Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1") with:
Dim arr
arr = Wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:K32").value
Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(Ubound(arr), Ubound(arr, 2)).value = arr

'your code
```